# How to limit the date values to allow a range of 45 days from today in an InfoPath date field?

Tags: infopath

I need to limit the date range of a Date Field or Date Picker in MS InfoPath 2013 to allow the user to only select a date that falls within 45 days from today.

Would like either a message box or screen tip to alert the user to enter a date less than 45 days in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a valifdation rule like the one mentioned below to achieve this. InfoPath does not support dialog box message for browser based forms (only the screen tip will work for browser based forms)
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reRJg.png)

Hopefully this helped you :)